# set session cookie attribute "Domain" on java-spring-tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, cookies

How can I set session cookie attribute "Domain" for my spring project on tomcat server?  I am using spring security and HTTPS
Currently I have following :

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONCookie: JSESSIONID=DEAC4422AB4E28A7062C08724C8BCFAA; Path=/myapp/; Secure; HttpOnly.
```

But I want this

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONCookie: JSESSIONID=DEAC4422AB4E28A7062C08724C8BCFAA; Path=/myapp/; Secure; Domain=.localhost; HttpOnly.
```

I have tried to put domain attribute in web.xml withing cookie-config.
I have tried using spring session [CookieHttpSessionStrategy], but that doesnot work.

There is something like TomcatContextCustomizer , but that doesnot work [actually I might have made some mistake in configuring it]

Also if running on localhost what domain should I set?

```
obj.setDomain("localhost");//or
obj.setDomain(".localhost");//or
obj.setDomain("127.0.0.1");
```

Which one of above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the tomcat configuration attribte: `sessionCookieDomain`

> The domain to be used for all session cookies created for this context. If set, this overrides any domain set by the web application. If not set, the value specified by the web application, if any, will be used.

```
<context  sessionCookiePath="/myapp/" sessionCookieDomain=".localhost">
...
</context>
```

in the global config `config/context.xml` or in an application specific context file.

@See [Tomcat configuration documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: Thanks This works. Although I am not able to find sessionCookieDomain value for localhost. So login fails as "session" cookie is not sent